# How to stop reinstalling VS Code Server over SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Remote - SSH extension for VS Code 9v 1.63.2) on Windows 10. I successfully connect to a linux remote machine and can edit my files remotely over the SSH server. But for some reason every time I boot up this project, it deletes, redownloads, and re-installs the server. This takes a while with my internet connection. Anyway to force it to re-use the existing install?

A sample log:

```
Acquiring lock on /home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/vscode-remote-lock.myuser.899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Found old VS Code install f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f, attempting to clean up
Deleting old install from /home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f
rm: cannot remove '/home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f': Directory not empty
Deleting old log file from /home/rmchh/.vscode-server/.f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f.log
Installing to /home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3...
172891dd6284%%1%%
Downloading with wget
wget download failed
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/server-linux-x64/stable: 2021-12-17 03:44:39 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
printenv:
    PWD=/home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
    ...
```